# Referencing a React-Redux TypeScript component in another TypeScript component causes a "no export member" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have the following TypeScript (v3.01) React component named TopBar to which I'm now adding React-Redux. The TopBar component is then referenced in a parent component named Layout.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { decrementZoomLevel, incrementZoomLevel, setCenterPoint, setZoomLevel } from '../store/actions';

class TopBar extends React.Component<any, any>{
...
};

/*
 * Redux-React setup
*/
const mapStateToProps = (state: any): any => {
  return {
    centerPoint: state.centerPoint,
    zoomLevel: state.zoomLevel
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TopBar);
```

However, when I reference this component in another Layout TypeScript component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TopBar } from './TopBar';

export class Layout extends React.Component<any, any> {
...
};
```

I get the following TypeScript error

*(TS) Module: "C:/....../TopBar" has no exported member 'TopBar'.*

Prior to adding the React-Redux code the class definition was

```
export default class TopBar extends React.Component<any, any>{
...
};
```

and I was able to reference the TopBar component in Layout w/ no errors.

Now that I'm adding the React-Redux connect() statement how do I properly reference TopBar in another component?

Answer (score 3):

It is a default export, you have to import this way.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import TopBar from './TopBar';

export class Layout extends React.Component<any, any> {
...
};
```

Comment: When I use this import statement I get the error "(TS) Can not find the name TopBar" for any reference to TopBar in the Layout component.

Comment: I ran into this issue too. `import { TopBar } from './TopBar';` probably worked before because it wasn't the default export. Now that it is the default export it should be changed to `import TopBar from './TopBar';`